# How do you set up multiple orbiting canvas drawings (pure js)

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

I am making a solar system with pre-made planets and want to know how to get more than one to rotate around the sun. I ran into the issue of not being able to rotate 2 at once. Any solutions?Here is current code:

Orbiting page: 
  `var canvasP = document.getElementById("planetsOrbit");
   var ctx2 = canvasP.getContext("2d");
   var angle = 6 * Math.PI / 180;`

```
var cx = window.innerWidth / 2;
var cy = window.innerHeight / 2.12;
var radiusNew = (window.innerHeight + window.innerWidth) * 0.15;



function resizeCanvasPOrbit() {
ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvasP.width, canvasP.height);
 if (canvasP.width < window.innerWidth) {
   canvasP.width = window.innerWidth * 0.99;
   }' 

  if (canvasP.height < window.innerHeight)
   {
    canvasP.height = window.innerHeight * 0.98;
    }
w = canvasP.width
h = canvasP.height
}


 function draw(x, y) {
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx2.save();
   ctx2.beginPath();
   ctx2.beginPath();
   roa(x, y, window.innerHeight * window.innerWidth * 0.00008);
   ctx2.stroke();
   ctx2.restore();
 };

  function keepDrawing() {
     ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
     draw(newX, newY);
     setTimeout(keepDrawing, 250);
 }

 window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
   return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
       window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
       function (callback) { 
        window.setTimeout(callback, 5000 / 60); 
        };
      })();

 var fps = 60;

 function animate() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // increase the angle of rotation A.K.A SPEED!
    angle += 1 * Math.PI / 3600;

    //calculate the new ball.x / ball.y
    var newX = cx - radiusNew * Math.cos(angle);
       var newY = cy + radiusNew * Math.sin(angle);

       //draw
      ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      draw(newX, newY);

       //draw the centerpoint 
      ctx2.beginPath();
      ctx2.arc(cx, cy, radiusNew, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx2.closePath();

  }, 1000 / fps);
 }
animate();
```

and the Premade Planets:

//sun

```
 solus = function(xAxis, yAxis, radius) {
ctx.shadowBlur=400
ctx.shadowColor="red"
ctx.fillStyle ="#ff9900";
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.arc(xAxis, yAxis, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)     
ctx.fill();
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
}

//Fighting Pits
pits = function(xAxis, yAxis, radius) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle ="#990000"
ctx.arc(xAxis, yAxis, radius, 0, Math.PI , false)     
ctx.moveTo(xSpot1,ySpot1)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot1,ySpot2)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot2,ySpot2)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot2,ySpot3)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot3,ySpot4)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot4,ySpot3)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot4,ySpot2)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot5,ySpot2)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot5,ySpot1)
ctx.lineTo(xSpot1,ySpot1)
ctx.fill();

} 



 //Water Planet

 roa = function(xAxis, yAxis, radius) {
 ctx2.shadowBlur = 0;
 ctx2.beginPath(); 
 ctx2.fillStyle ="#00ffff"
 ctx2.arc(xAxis, yAxis, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false) 
 ctx2.fill();

 }


//Forest planet atmoshpere
eldridA = function(xAxis, yAxis, radius) {
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.fillStyle ="rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.3)";
ctx.arc(xAxis, yAxis, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false) 
ctx.fill();

}
//forest core
eldrid = function(xAxis, yAxis, radius) {
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2)";
ctx.shadowBlur = 200;
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.fillStyle ="#ff9900"
ctx.arc(xAxis, yAxis, radius / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false) 
ctx.fill();
xAxis2 = xAxis - window.innerWidth * 0.009 
yAxis2 = yAxis + window.innerHeight * 0.007
ctx.arc(xAxis2, yAxis2, radius / 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, false) 
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
xAxis3 = xAxis + window.innerWidth * 0.011
ctx.arc(xAxis3 , yAxis2, radius / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false) 
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
yAxis3 = yAxis - window.innerHeight * 0.03 
ctx.arc(xAxis, yAxis3, radius / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false) 
ctx.fill();
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
ctx.shadowColor = null;
}
```

So how can I get more than one planet to orbit the Sun? any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple demo of a solar system with multiple planets using canvas: http://codepen.io/giladaya/pen/PWWKLP

I believe that you can easily adapt it to your needs and I'll explain the main parts of the code:

Each planet has it's own properties like radius, distance from center, radial velocity and a reference to a draw function.

```
var planets = [
  {
    name: 'sun',      // for reference
    rad: 30,          // Planet radius
    distance: 0,      // Planet distance from center
    rv: 0,            // radial velocity (deg/sec)
    drawFunc: drawSun // draw function
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    rad: 10,
    distance: 70,
    rv: 1,
    drawFunc: drawBlue
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    rad: 15,
    distance: 100,
    rv: 2,
    drawFunc: drawRed
  }
];
```

The main loop iterates over all the planets, updates their current angle according to the radial velocity and draws each one in it's new, updated location.

```
function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(-cW/2, -cH/2, cW, cH);

  var now = Date.now(), 
      dts = (now - lastFrameTime) / 1000;
  planets.forEach(function(planet, idx){
    var theta = 0;
    planetsAngle[idx] += planet.rv/Math.PI * dts;
    theta = planetsAngle[idx];
    var x = planet.distance * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = planet.distance * Math.sin(theta);
    planet.drawFunc(ctx, x, y, planet.rad);
  });
  lastFrameTime = now;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Note that if using requestAnimationFrame, you don't need to set timers.

The draw function for each planet can be as complicated as you want in order to have more elements on the planet. For example:

```
function drawRed(ctx, x, y, rad) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, rad, 0, 2*Math.PI , false);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#A00';
  ctx.fillRect(-4, -4, 8, 8);
  ctx.restore();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Giladd, should help out tremendously, and allow me to finish up tommorow.